# polyline second path to draggable div

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

How can I simply draw a line between two lat long coordinates values on a map using ESRI ArcGIS JS API?! This most basic task is taking a gruesome amount of effort.

I am able to draw a line with the below, but it's not reading my latitude and longitude coordinate values as such, instead it's taking the point to some arbitrary destination.

```
require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"
    ], function(Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) {

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "topo-vector"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",  
    map: map,
    center: [-118.80500,34.02700],
    zoom: 13
  });

  var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
  map.add(graphicsLayer);  

  // Create a point
   var point = {
   type: "point",
   longitude: -118.80657463861,
   latitude: 34.0005930608889
  };

  var simpleMarkerSymbol = {
   type: "simple-marker",
   color: [226, 119, 40],  // orange
   outline: {
     color: [255, 255, 255], // white
     width: 1
   }
  };

  var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
   geometry: point,
   symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol
  });

  graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);

  // Create a line geometry
  var simpleLineSymbol = {
     type: "simple-line",
     color: [226, 119, 40], // orange
     width: 2
   };

   var polyline = {
     type: "polyline",
     paths: [
       [35.9411934679851, -80.96135253906438], 
       [-118.808878330345, 34.0016642996246]
     ]
   };

   var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
     geometry: polyline,
     symbol: simpleLineSymbol
   })

   graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);

  var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
   geometry: polygon,
   symbol: simpleFillSymbol
  });

  graphicsLayer.add(polygonGraphic);

});
```

This block specifically, I simply just want to feed in two sets of lat and long coordinates values.... i.e. `CoordinatesA` and `CoordinatesB` *(as the startpoint and endpoint, why is this so difficult)*

```
   var polyline = {
     type: "polyline",
     paths: [
       [35.9411934679851, -80.96135253906438], 
       [-118.808878330345, 34.0016642996246]
     ]
   };
```

CodePen https://codepen.io/camerondevcam/pen/PowjVqq?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be an issue with the order of LAT/LON. I tried by using mentioned code and it draws a line from EAST to WEST across USA.

```
var polyline = {
          type: "polyline", // autocasts as new Polyline()
         paths: [
       [-80.96135253906438,35.9411934679851], //interchanged the values
       [-118.808878330345, 34.0016642996246]
     ]
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/n09czL2k/